# Seanborn: plot 3rd variable on scatterplor

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn

I have a dataframe that has been filtered by condition:

```
df2 = df[['longitude', 'latitude', 'price']]
df_Scatter = df2[df2['price']>150]
```

the df_Scatter now appears as:

```
    longitude   latitude    price
1   4.89354 52.36509    236
6   4.84838 52.35132    219
7   4.88321 52.37891    160
8   4.88932 52.37537    211
13  4.86103 52.36266    250
... ... ... ...
18482   4.87564 52.37167    176
18496   4.88266 52.37398    250
18516   4.92186 52.35830    275
18517   4.91443 52.36978    330
18518   4.87967 52.36404    350
6288 rows × 3 columns
```

I want to plot `longitude` and `latitude` as the coordinates and **encode : price** to size and colour of plot.

This is what I have so far.

```
plt.scatter(df_Scatter.longitude, df_Scatter.latitude, c=df_Scatter.price, s = df_Scatter.price)
plt.show()
```

which returns **two errors**

```
AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'sqrt'

TypeError: loop of ufunc does not support argument 0 of type int which has no callable sqrt method
```

and an empty plot where axis range from 0-1.

**Does the following error return due to difference in datatypes?**
the example plot that im aiming for, has a legend on its chart in which price is still in INT format when encoded into the colour and size of plot.

Comment: `sns.scatterplot(data=df, x="longitude", y="latitude", c=df["price"], s=df["price"])`?

Comment: Or `df.plot.scatter(x="longitude", y="latitude", c="price", s="price")`?

Comment: first one returns : ValueError: s must be a scalar, or the same size as x and y

Comment: You should change the `df` to your subset variable

Comment: of course, and i did so. 
The second suggestion:  TypeError: ```ufunc 'sqrt' not supported for the input types, and the inputs could not be safely coerced to any supported types according to the casting rule ''safe''```

Comment: Are you running the latest matplotlib and pandas versions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TRY with `seaborn`:

```
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

ax = sns.scatterplot(x=df['longitude'], y=df['latitude'], size = df['price'], hue= df['price'])
```

#### OUTPUT:

[image]

Comment: thanks. I debugged my problem: Price needed to be a float. I will work with the code provided to add additional information/ change figsize etc